# How do I add stock portlets (from plone.app.portlets) to my custom portlet manager?

Tags: plone

Using the [documentation](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/elements/portletmanager/practical/adding-portlet-managers) on plone.org along with some in the forum, I was able to get a custom portlet manager below my content in Plone 4.0.8. The goal, actually, is to have 4 custom managers below the content arranged like the dashboard.

Anyway, my manager only allows me to add static and collection portlets. After looking around in the code, I found that when the system goes to populate that 'Add new portlet' dropdown, it loops through all of the portlets. Then, it loops through each portlet's 'for_' attribute checking to see if the interfaces are provided by self--my portlet manager.

```
def getAddablePortletTypes(self):
    addable = []
    for p in getUtilitiesFor(IPortletType):
        # BBB - first condition, because starting with Plone 3.1                                                                                                                                  
        #every p[1].for_ should be a list                                                                                                                                                         
        if not isinstance(p[1].for_, list):
            logger.warning("Deprecation Warning ..." % p[1].addview)
            if p[1].for_ is None or p[1].for_.providedBy(self):
                addable.append(p[1])
        elif [i for i in p[1].for_ if i.providedBy(self)]:
            addable.append(p[1])
    return addable
```

How do I add my manager's interface to each portlet's 'for_' list of interfaces?

Comment: I changed my manager's interface from

`class IBottomPortletManager(IPortletManager)`
to

`class IBottomPortletManager(IPortletManager, IColumn)`

IColumn is defined in plone.app.portlets, so those portlets are already registered for managers that provide IColumn.

Now, is this the ideal way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080053/how-do-i-add-stock-portlets-from-plone-app-portlets-to-my-custom-portlet-manage#comment-8474301) is probably the best way to do this.  The crux here is that portlets themselves are registered to a portlet manager interface, among other interfaces for contexts, layers, etc..  Another way to do this, for example, would be to add additional registrations in your profiles/default/portlets.xml file to your portlet manager interface for each of the portlets you want addable:

```
<portlet
  addview="portlets.News"
  title="News"
  description="A portlet which can render a listing of recent news"
  i18n:attributes="title;
                   description"
  >
  <for interface="your.package.IYourPortletManager" />
</portlet>
```

Your way is probably best, however, since it sounds like you *are* creating a columnar portlet manager.  You could remove IPortletManager from the base classes, however, since IColumn already subclasses it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I add additional registrations to my manager interface? Suppose I'm only using IPortletManager as a base, but I also want News portlets. How do I add my manager interface to the News portlet registrations? I've been looking around in plone.app.portlets trying to figure out how these portlets register interfaces without any luck yet.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.